# Cannot read HTML5 video from local cache after using video.load()

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I want to play a list of mp4 videos from local cache to save network traffic. 
I am pretty sure the videos are in my cache because when I manually switch file 1.mp4,2.mp4,3.mp4,4.mp4 on video source, the "Network" panel of chrome development tools shows the file is served from cache even it returns HTTP 206.

When I try to use javascript for the video playlist, after the new video is loaded, chrome start to miss the cache and try to get the video from internet and hence cost network traffic.

> video.load();

Is there way to make chrome to load the video from cache?

Browser:
Chrome ver.50

HTML:

```
<div id="video">
  <video id="video-ads" autoplay preload="none">
    <source id="video-source" src="https://foo.bar.net/video/1.mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var cdn = "https://foo.bar.net";    
var playList = new Array(
    cdn + "/video/1.mp4",    
    cdn + "/video/2.mp4",
    cdn + "/video/3.mp4"
);
var videoCount = playList.length;
var i = 0;
video = document.getElementById("video-ads");
videoSource = document.getElementById("video-source");
video.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    if (i == videoCount) i = 0;
    var nextVideo = playList[i++];
    videoSource.setAttribute("src", nextVideo);  
    video.load();
    video.play();
});
```